# GWT EntryPoint onModuleLoad() @Override annotation causing errors

Tags: eclipse, gwt

In Eclipse, creating a GWT EntryPoint results in some generated code that looks like this:

```
public class Main implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // TODO implement
    }
}
```

The EntryPoint interface declares a single method: `void onModuleLoad`. If I add a `@Override` annotation to `onModuleLoad`, however, Eclipse throws an error: `The method onModuleLoad() of type Main must override a superclass method.`

My app runs fine (without the annotation), and I'm curious as to why this might happen. Any ideas?

- GWT 2.4.0
- Eclipse Indigo (3.7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up your project to use Java 6.

Comment: @Shahzeb http://dertompson.com/2008/01/25/override-specification-changes-in-java-6/